# How to create ionic2 javascript project?

Tags: javascript, ionic2

Before Ionic2 RC there was possible to create a pure JS template with Ionic CLI

Now it always creates a TypeScript template, no matter what keys I'm supplying.

I was trying `--javascript`, `--no-ts`, `--js`

no luck.

documentation also giving nothing about it.

Is there any way to create a pure js template using ionic2 cli ?

My old project was developed with js template, and now I cannot move to RC.

Comment: *I was trying --javascript, --no-ts, --js* this is actually funny way of doing things :D

Comment: Yes, cause some of there options was googled, and `--ts` was a key to create a TypeScript template before RC. Funny that their docs says nothing about it now...

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that a few weeks ago I asked that in **ionic-v2** Slack channel and the answer from one developer from Ionic Team was:

> We're going all in on TS.
>
> You could do your own work and covert it toa es6 workflow, but **we want
>   people to use typescript**

So Typescript is not optional for Ionic 2 applications.

There's also an [Why TypeScript](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/resources/typescript/) section in Ionic2 resource pages where Ionic Team explains the benefits of using TypeScript:

> TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript that gives you advantages like:
>
> - Optional static typing (the key here is optional)
> - Type Inference,
>     which gives some of the benefits of types, without actually using them
> - Access to ES6 and ES7 features, before they become supported by major
>     browsers
> - The ability to compile down to a version of JavaScript that
>     runs on all browsers
> - Great tooling support with IntelliSense Because
>     of these awesome features and the huge advantages it gives to you as a
>     developer, Ionic 2 apps are written in TypeScript, instead of ES6.